# How to implement the reflow to the scroll into particular div when loads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to scroll into particular div when page is loads. I have mentioned the css id in url with #.

The page contains 4 div sections, The div contents are displayed slowly. So i think the height is not set properly so the scroll is not working.

**Issue:**
Did not scrolled into expected div. But, Once the page is loaded it is working fine on click.

**My code is:**

```
goTo = jQuery('#content3');
jQuery('html,body').animate({
    'scrollTop': goTo
}, 1000);
```

How to resolve this issue with reflow method?

Thanks for advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set offset top of div element and this will work,

```
goTo = $('#content3').offset().top;
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  goTo = $('#content3').offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
    'scrollTop': goTo
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content3">Content 3</div>
<div id="content4">Content 4</div>
```

Comment: The solution is working but Content 1, Content 2, Content 3 values are loads dynamically, so it is not scrolled content3.

Comment: Use your code in `$(document).ready` or `onload` function, it will trigger your code after entire page is loaded including dynamic content.